# Burger Button Display Not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, responsive

I want the burger to show up when my screen size is lesser than 1023px.

It is not happening only when using media query

```css
.burger {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 5%;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1053px) {
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<button
  type="button"
  class="burger"
  data-toggle="collapse"
  data-target="#myNavbar"
>
  &#9776;
</button>
```

But the burger icon is not appearing although I've tried creating burger from span and I tags

Comment: it seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ho8z9s0p/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work perfectly for me when testing on codepen. Can you check how your stylesheet is connected in your HTML document, as in this piece of code.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
```

In the `<head>` section of your html document. I have a feeling that it might not be connected.

EDIT

html

```
<button
    type="button"
    id="burger"
    data-toggle="collapse"
    data-target="#myNavbar"
        >
          &#9776;
</button>
```

CSS

```
#burger {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 5%;
    top: 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    background: none;
    border: none; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1053px) {
      #burger {
        display: block;
   
    }
}
```

Comment: hey rory thanks for responding, but my stylesheet is connected correctly, the other pieces of code seems to work properly only this button code is not working,

Comment: Hmm. Try this as a last resort then. Edited my above answer

Comment: not working buddy;)

Comment: Ah crud. If you have this committed to a github repo I'd be happy to take a look. I'm really stumped at why this doesn't work, and I have a feeling it could be a small typo somewhere rather than a big problem.

Comment: i have its old version that was not responsive,I haven't committed the new one yet as it is  unstable